# Get current user in Django not working in tests

Tags: python, django

I have a couple of views in my Django app that perform and action and record who did the action in the DB, something like:

```
def my_view(request):
    # do some stuff here first
    current_user = MyCustomUserObject.objects.filter(django_user_id=request.user.id).first()
    model_i_did_something_to_above.last_modified_by = current_user
    model.save()
```

And this actually works fine if I run the server and call it via postman. However, when I do a Unit test:

```
from datetime import datetime

class MyTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        now = datetime.utcnow()
        django_user = User.objects.create_user(username='myusername',
                                           email='test@test.com',
                                           password='abcd')
        
        self.user = MyCustomUserObject(user_name='myusername', email_address='test@test.com', created_datetime=now,
                    last_modified_datetime=now, is_admin=True, django_user=django_user)
        self.user.save()
        self.tokens = json.loads(self.client.post(reverse('authenticate'),
                                                  data={'username': 'myusername',
                                                        'password': 'abcd'},
                                                  content_type='application/json').content)

    def test_stuff(self):
        self.client.delete(reverse('nameoftheurl'),
                               {data: 'stuff'},
                               content_type='application/json',
                               **{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': self.tokens['access']})
```

And it reaches the view, it says that request.user.id is None. Why does this happen? Is there a way around this?

**EDIT**

The authenticate view goes like this:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

urlpatterns = [
    path('authenticate/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='authenticate'),
    ]
```

I also updated the test example above to show how the user is created.

Comment: Can you share what the authenticate view looks like? And how did you create the user before authenticate in the tests?

Comment: @bdbd please see my edit to answer those questions!

Comment: @rodrigocf  Can you try adding  `self.user.refresh_from_db()` right after `self.user.save()` in the setup func in Unit Test.

Comment: Please add the code (could be a middleware) which is responsible for setting the `request.user` from the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be because your authorization header has the authorization type missing in your `test_stuff` test case.

It should be:

```
headers={'Authorization': f"Bearer {self.tokens['access']}"}
```

So:

```
    def test_stuff(self):
        self.client.delete(reverse('nameoftheurl'),
                               {data: 'stuff'},
                               content_type='application/json',
                               **{'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION': f"Bearer {self.tokens['access']}")
                                                       #  ^^^ Add this
```

Comment: This is it. I can't believe it was this this simple. Since the bounty expired, I started it again and will award the points tomorrow night. Life saver, big time. @bdbd

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to log your user in:

```
class MyTests(TestCase):

    ...

    def test_stuff(self):
        self.client.force_login(self.user)
        self.client.delete(
            reverse('nameoftheurl'),
            {data: 'stuff'},
            content_type='application/json',
            HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=self.tokens['access'],
        )
```

A snippet from the **[`authentication docs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)**:

> If the current user has not logged in, this attribute will be set to an instance of AnonymousUser, otherwise it will be an instance of User.

An **`AnonymousUser`** has it's **`id`** set to `None`, hence your error.

On a side-note, this also indicates a bug in your delete view.  You should check that a user is logged in before trying to log them out, otherwise you will end up returning a 500 error at some point (if not already).